# Elementary question in reductive group

Tags: algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

I am very sorry for asking some elementary question.

Let $G$ be a reductive group over a number field $F$ and $N$ a unipotent radical of some parabolic subgroup of $G$.

Then I am wondering whether $G \times N$ is a reductive group?

I will appreciate if you give me an answer in this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Asking an elementary question *is not a problem* on this site.  Asking any question, with **no context** *is THE problem here*.  I shouldn't have to tutor you wrt how to ask a good question, given your rep; but please see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: The radical of an algebraic group is the largest normal closed, connected,solvable subgroup.  A group is reductive if the radical has no unipotent elements.  If $R(G)$ is the radical of $G$, what can you say about the radical of $G \times N$?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/318873

Comment: Please do not crosspost.